# How to remove the optional call for 'library-preload.json' in SAPUI5 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, sapui5

I am developing a SAPUI5 mobile app using cordova. Now I need to include another library (cordova-plugin-file) into my project. I've already tried to do this, but my problem is, that if the plugin is included, my 'sap-ui-core.js' file tries to load 'library-preload.json' (see screenshot).

[screenshot console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z14rS.png)

And I do not want to load a library-preload.json. How could I solve this problem?
An Answer on how to solve this problem by adding a 'library-preload.json' file 
would also not be bad :)

Comment: Hi, as far as I know you can't. I already asked SAPUI5 Devs by SAP, and they mentioned this as a feature.

Comment: okay :( And do you have an idea on how to fix this error by adding library-preload.json file? I don't know what this file/ these files should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `data-sap-ui-preload=""` in SAPUI5 Boostrapping.

To Quote from Source:

> The library-preload.json files which contain all controls from a
>   library to reduce the number of HTTP requests are not required in
>   hybrid apps because there is no HTTP latency. SAPUI5 will by default
>   try to access them, so you might see a failed attempt to load these
>   files in the log file or developer tools. These error messages do not
>   hurt, though, and you can get rid of them by declaring that no such
>   files exist and by setting the following configuration in the SAPUI5
>   bootstrap script tag:

```
       `data-sap-ui-preload="" `
```

Read: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/293eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533.html

Preload has 3 more variants. Read More here: 
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f1cea36f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/frameset.htm?original_fqdn=help.sap.de